# Datetime.Now.Millisecond not showing full time format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

While creating a log I am using `Datetime.Now.Millisecond`. But I am getting only millisecond. I am not getting the full time like `11/09/2015 10:59:48:936` but getting only `936`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [`Millisecond` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.millisecond%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `int` it's millisecond part.

> The milliseconds component, expressed as a value between `0` and `999`.

If you wanna get full time format as you want, you can generate it's string representation as;

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [DateTime.Now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx) and then call `ToString` [with appropriate format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) to get output the way you want

```
var result = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvarianCutlure);
```